# Google Cloud - Node jS + Python. How to install requirements.txt?

Tags: python, node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, python-module

I have a Google Cloud Node project, which runs some python code through child_process

The code in my machine runs well, however when the code is run in the server it fails because the python modules are not found.

I'm trying to install the modules in requirements.txt but setting it up on root folder doesn't work as it isn't a python env in the yaml file.

Testing is really slow (about 20 minutes to deploy) so I am wondering if anyone knows how to install those modules.

Comment: Is this GAE Standard or Flex? perhaps you could elaborate more on what you're trying to do. You probably need to setup a separate microservice for python and use the taskqueue to communicate with it.

Comment: Separate out your different language runtimes into their own services so that you have a separate requirements file for each.

Comment: @Alex It is FLEX, node has always been flex until some days ago.

Comment: @swigganicks  that would be easier but each instance incurs in additional costs

Comment: Then I would create a custom flex environment and package everything you need into a docker container. That way you have full control over dependencies

Comment: @swigganicks looks like you have provided a proper answer in comments. Would you like to post it as such and earn some points?